# How to stop progress dialog after execute sending parameter to remote server android

Tags: android, parameters, send

I was successfully sending parameter to remote server, but I have problem : i have checked my table, data is already inserted but the progressbar always spins and doesnt stop, do you know how to stop the progressbar after I click button Send ?

Here my source code :

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Timeline extends Activity {
    //private ProgressBar pb;
    private String status;
    final int PROGRESS_DIALOG=1;
    private ProgressBar pb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeline);

        final RadioButton rbtnlisting=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnlisting);
        final RadioButton rbtnclosing=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnclosing);
        final RadioButton rbtnprospek=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnprospek);      
        final EditText edtstatus=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtstatus);
        Button btnpost=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpost);

        edtstatus.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getBaseContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen.lbltitlelistviewitem));
        btnpost.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getBaseContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen.lbltitlelistviewitem));
        rbtnlisting.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getBaseContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen.lbltitlelistviewitem));
        rbtnclosing.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getBaseContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen.lbltitlelistviewitem));
        rbtnprospek.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getBaseContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen.lbltitlelistviewitem));  

        pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);        

        btnpost.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                           
                if (edtstatus.getText().length()>5) {
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    TheTask async=new TheTask();
                    async.execute("ccc");
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your status is too short", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }           
            }
        });
    }
    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>
    {
        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {         
            postData(params[0]);
            return null;            
        }       

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Status telah diposting !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            RadioButton rbtnlisting=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnlisting);
            RadioButton rbtnclosing=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnclosing);
            RadioButton rbtnprospek=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnprospek);        
            EditText edtstatus=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtstatus);          

            if (edtstatus.getText().length()>5) {
                if (rbtnclosing.isSelected()) {status="Closing";}
                else if (rbtnprospek.isSelected()) {status="Prospek";}
                else if (rbtnlisting.isSelected()) {status="Listing";}          

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dummy/insert.php");
                try {               
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idsales",OtherClass.getIdSales().toString()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jenis", status));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("remark", edtstatus.getText().toString()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("path", "coba coba"));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "masuk", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
                catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "gagal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                  
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "gagal2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }                   

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your status is too short", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }       


    }
}
```

Comment: not crash, but progressbar has been spinning, and data is successfully inserted to table on remote server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onPostExecute()` method isn't being called because it has the wrong signature. When you created your `AsyncTask` subclass, you specified the following types:

```
AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>
```

Therefore, your `onPostExecute()` method needs the following signature:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Double result)
```

Also, I believe if you annotate your methods with `@Override`, your IDE should warn you that it's incorrect. (I think.)

Answer (score 0):

onPostExecution() dismiss() your progressbar

```
    pb.dissmiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
//In your onPre

```
 If(!pb.isShowing)
 {
  pb.show();
 }
 else
 {
     //
 }
```

//In your onpost

```
If(pb.isShowing)
{
 pb.dismiss();
}
else
{
  //
}
```

Hope this ll work....